# Run a short lived background task for excel generation in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-poi

In my project the requirement is to generate the **EXCEL** file (I did it with POI) in back ground process.
When user click on excel generate then a background process will work and generate an excel and give notification to user the excel is ready to download (did it with Velocity). 
I have more than 20 task in which need to generate an excel file. All task should run in background so that user can access the whole application smoothly. 
The database we are using to fetch the data for excel file is **MYSQL**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need to generate an excel report using back ground process because file is too heavy and can take more than an minute.

Comment: Please let us know in which way you want to notify the user than the processing is done (email? websocket? poll?). Also, let us know your servlet version (for async or not) .How long does the processing take?

Comment: i am notifying the user with email and servlet version (3.0.1) and it can not take more than 1 minute.

Comment: You want to write the DB data into Excel using apache POI?

Comment: @VigNesh yes i am fetching the record from database and making it excel.

Answer (score -3):

[image]Create a new excel file

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
//..
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
//Create a new row in current sheet
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
//Create a new cell in current row
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
//Set value to new value
cell.setCellValue("Blahblah");
```

Below is the complete code that writes a new excel with dummy data:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");

        Map<string, object[]=""> data = new HashMap<string, object[]="">();
        data.put("1", new Object[] {"Emp No.", "Name", "Salary"});
        data.put("2", new Object[] {1d, "John", 1500000d});
        data.put("3", new Object[] {2d, "Sam", 800000d});
        data.put("4", new Object[] {3d, "Dean", 700000d});

        Set<string> keyset = data.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                if(obj instanceof Date) 
                    cell.setCellValue((Date)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Boolean)
                    cell.setCellValue((Boolean)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Double)
                    cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = 
                    new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\new.xls"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The question is not how to create excel. There is a long process which should be done in background. What is the best way to implement this scenario.

Comment: Where is thread to import and expert all these data in background.